# Magnitude spectrum of sine wave and Dirac delta

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, dirac-delta

On [this website](https://www.ques10.com/p/3692/obtain-the-fourier-transform-of-a-sine-wave-havi-1/) I found the following drawing of the magnitude spectrum of a sine wave along with the derivation of the Fourier Transform of $\sin(x)$, given by $X(f) = \frac{1}{2j}\left[\delta(f−f_0) - \delta(f+f_0)\right]$, and the following explanation:

> The term $\delta(f−f_0)$ is a delta function in the frequency domain which is shifted right by frequency “$f_0$” .Its amplitude is $+\frac{1}{2}$ and the term $\delta(f+f_0)$ represents a delta function which is shifted left by frequency “$f_0$”.Its amplitude is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

[image]

To me, this seems to suggest that $\delta(0) = 1$, but this does clearly not coincide with the definition of the Dirac delta function. For, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions) states, "the Dirac delta can be loosely thought of as a function on the real line which is zero everywhere except at the origin, where it is infinite,
$$
\delta(x) \simeq
\begin{cases}
    +\infty & \text{if } x=0\\
    0 & \text{if } x\neq 0
\end{cases}
$$
and which is also constrained to satisfy the identity $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \text{d}x = 1$."

I would really appreciate any help to clear up my confusion about this!

Comment: $1/2$-factors are only relative amplitudes associated to $\pm f_0$; it means that each frequency contributes equally, but the whole expression still has to be considered inside an integral to make sense.

Comment: You are correct.  The Dirac Delta is not a function, it is a distribution (or a measure).  It does not assume values and does not have an argument.   The graph is only an heuristic representation of the Fourier transform, which is a tempered distribution on the Schwartz space of functions.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! Could you point me to any learning resources to understand the meaning of this "heuristic representation" (and its limitations) better? Many thanks again